# Use defined constants from parent theme in child theme in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a theme and was wondering if the following is possible. I want to define some constants in parent theme to be usable in a child theme. But, since `Wordpress loads child themes functions.php` file before parents `functions.php`, my constants always return the literal string. For example:

In parents theme:

```
define('THEME_VERSION', 1.0);
```

In child theme:

```
var_dump(THEME_VERSION);
```

returns the string `'THEME_VERSION'` (with a warning, that a constant is not defined) and not the number.

Is there anything I can do here without defining constants in my child theme?

Comment: Where did you define constants in the parent theme?

Comment: First thing in parent themes functions.php file

Comment: @destripet not a good idea to be modifying the parent theme.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz I guess I forgot to meantion that the parent theme is also developed by me

Answer (score 0):

WordPress loads `functions.php` file of `child-theme` just before the `functions.php` file of `parent-theme`. So that you are getting the warning while using constants in functions.php file of child-theme from parent-theme.

[Here is the explanation of child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php)

Comment: Yeah, but I was wondering is it possible to define them in parent theme and use in child theme, without defining them in child theme.

Comment: Please read documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php

Answer (score 0):

The constants from child themes will be used instead of parents one. Though, there will be a warning, but that shouldn't create any problem if you disable warning.

You should add constants like this if you don't want any warning.

```
if ( !defined('CONSTANT') )
    define('CONSTANT', 'constant_value');
```

For more information you can see here.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157505/override-constants-in-child-theme?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa